# Java Null Pointer with String Array

Tags: java

I have been coding a basic method to take an array of strings, find the largest length and return a string array containing on values that are equal to the highest length of the array. I keep getting a null pointer exception and i am not sure why. The code is:

```
String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {
    int compare = 0;
    int k = 0;
    String[] use = new String[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i].length() > compare)
            compare = inputArray[i].length();

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        if (inputArray[j].length() - compare == 0) {
            use[k] = inputArray[j];
            k++;
        }

    }
    return use;

}
```

Comment: What's the exact error with trace? And have you done any debugging?

Comment: You don't appear to ever populate the `use` array.

Comment: post the exception logs. May be your inputArray is null.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at myCode._json_encode(file.java on line ?) at myCode.main(file.java on line ?) Caused by:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAcce‌​ssorImpl.java:62)at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMe‌​thodAccessorImpl.jav‌​a:43) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at myCode._json_encode(file.java on line ?)                   is what the console outputs

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    if (inputArray[j].length() - compare == 0) {
        use[k] = inputArray[j];
        k++;
    }
}
```

This will only work if `inputArray` has at least 20 elements. In the code above, you're doing the correct thing: `for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)`. I think you just need to change this second for statement to be the lesser of 20 or the length of inputArray.

Comment: I tried that, and it still gives the null pointer.

Comment: Want to share your modifications here?

Comment: String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {
        int compare = 0;
        int k = 0;
        String[] use = new String[20];
        for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
            if(inputArray[i].length() > compare)
                compare = inputArray[i].length();
        
    }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++){
            if(inputArray[j].length() - compare == 0){
            use[k] = inputArray[j];
            k++;
            }
        
    
        
    }
    return use;
    
    
}

Comment: How many strings are in inputArray?

Comment: it varies, but no more than 20 will be used in the tests.

Comment: I'm just not seeing it. Do you know what line you're getting the exception on? Do you have any sample data?

Comment: I know that the error is in the line  if (inputArray[j].length() - compare == 0) when I delete that line and run the program, the null pointer goes away.

Answer (score 0):

**inputArray** doesn't contain 20 elements. Don't just throw out and hard code a length value for your the array you're going to return. Actually determine what the true length is going to be because you could be too low on that value and if your not then you could end up with a bunch of null elements.

If allowed use an **[ArrayList](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist)** or String **[List](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html)** object which doesn't require a preset length (size) instead of a 1D String Array which does require **length** initialization: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`. You can simply just add to it with the **[List.add()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html)** method.

If you must use a Single Dimensional Array then use another **for** loop to determine how many string elements actually have the same length as what is held within the **compare** integer variable. Always iterate through the original array (**inputArray**). This **for** loop would be very much like your second **for** loop except you would increment a integer counter variable upon all elemental lengths that **equal** the value held within the **compare** variable.

Eliminate the formula in your **if** statement condition contained within your second **for** loop. I think (IMHO):  `if (inputArray[i].length() == compare) {...}` should be sufficient, it's much easier on the eyes.  ;)

Just a thought for pizazz....perhaps add the actual Array index to the string that is added to the 1D String array named **used**. Use a delimiter of some sort to separate the two.